# Maximizing $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

The problem is to maximize $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2$ over all $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Since the domain is compact and the function is continuous, it is certain that extrema must exist. Plus I figured out that the maximum is $\frac{1}{2}$ where $(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0)$ by Lagrange multiplier.

However, the calculation for Lagrange multiplier was quite long. This problem is from past problems of regional math contest which do not assume calculus knowledge.

Is there an elementary way to get the maximum?

Thanks in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

Comment: If you should ask me to maximise the distance between three positive numbers whose sum equals $1$, I would have the tendency to go for either $0$, $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ or $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$, just intuïvely.

Comment: Can you please explain what maximising means? Does it mean finding the maximum value?

Comment: @Gwen Yes, what I meant is finding the maximum value.

Comment: @Dominique I cannot see how your comment is related to the question.

Comment: You probably mean that the maximum is attained at $(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0)$

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wonder why my answer is not the one accepted? Because it is the first answer? because it is simpler? or because I have less reputation points? :)

Comment: @NN2 Your answer and Anne Bauval’s one both perfectly settled my question. I just randomly picked which one to accept(literally, by random number generator). Please don’t feel offended, your answer was clear and illuminating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume henceforth $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and wlog, $$x\ge y\ge z.$$

- On one hand, $$(x-z)^2-4(x-y)(y-z)=(x+z-2y)^2\ge0.$$
- On the other hand, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
  $$x-z=\langle(x,y,z),(1,0,-1)\rangle\le\|(x,y,z)\|\|(1,0,-1)\|=\sqrt2.$$
  Therefore,
  $$(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)\le\frac{(x-z)^3}4\le\frac1{\sqrt2},$$
  so that
  $$(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(x-z)^2\le\frac12,$$
  with equality iff $x+z-2y=0$ and $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R(1,0,-1)$, i.e.
  $$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},0,-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).$$

Answer (score 9):

WOLG, suppose that $x\ge y \ge z$ and denote
$$L:= \left((x-y)(y-z)(x-z)\right)^2$$
Applying the AM-GM inequality to $(x-y),(y-z)$ and $(x-z)/2$:
$$\begin{align}
&(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)\le 2\cdot \left(\frac{(x-y)+(y-z)+\frac{x-z}{2}}{3} \right)^3 =\frac{(x-z)^3}{4}\\
\implies &L\le \frac{(x-z)^6}{16}\end{align}$$
We have also that
$$(x-z)^2 \le 2\left(x^2+(-z)^2  \right)\le 2(x^2+y^2 +z^2) = 2$$
We deduce then
$$\color{red}{L \le \frac{1}{2}}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $\cases{x = -z\\y = 0 \\x^2+y^2 +z^2 = 1} \iff (x,y,z) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)$

And of course you can also permute $x$,$y$,$z$ and have six solutions.

Comment: (+1) Your answer inspired mine.

Comment: @AnneBauval You're welcome! +1 to your answer also :).